# Program works in next 30 years with QGIS over multiple layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, iteration

For an asset management plan, I want to create a table that programs work for the next 30years.  For a given layer, I want to use the start date and the project into future either replacements or maintenance tasks.  For example:

- Valve (point) - replaced every 15 years at $5000
- Pipe (line) - replace every 80 years at $600m, inspect every 5 years at $10/m

Ideally I want to output a table with where for each data point I have the cost of the work required inserted in the correct attribute reflecting a future year.  I currently do this in Excel, but was hoping to use GIS as:

- The replacement dates vary based on condition and material, adopted from nearby similar data points
- Cost is based on geographical features - eg amount crossing roads, urban or rural areas, etc
- Want to update for when new assets are added and subtracted.

I am familiar with using the graphical modeller to generate a new layer and field with the Field Calculator option.

Is it possible to iterate over this function 30 times and create a new attribute in the same layer each time representing a subsequent year?

Comment: What is your question? Whether your idea is feasible? How to achieve this? How to iterate?

Comment: Hi Erik, I hope that is clearer. Is it possible to repeat a function in graphical modeller a set number of times (eg Field Calculator repeated 30 times in my case)